# Как обратиться к этому биту?

Tags: c#, сборщик-мусора

Речь идёт о реализации механизма "Mark and Sweep", для которой нужно обращаться к объекту и помечать его. Обращаться нужно именно к биту объекта(бит, указывающий, достижим ли этот объект из программы или нет), обратившись и изменив значение которого я смогу продолжить реализацию этого алгоритма. Так вот, как обратиться к этому биту?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Никогда не вставляйте текст картинкой. Копируйте его и оформляйте ввиде цитаты, если есть необходимость. Указывайте ссылку, если это общедоступный материал.

Answer (score 2):

Всё просто:

- `x | (1 << n)` – установка бита
- `x & ~(1 << n)` – обнуление бита
- `x ^ (1 << n)` – переключение бита

Тут `x` – исходное число (`int`, `long`, ...), а `n` – позиция бита.

---

Или же можно использовать `enum`:

```
enum ObjectAttributes
{
    ...
    IsCollected = 0x1, // или 0x2, 0x4, 0x8, 0x10, 0x20, ...
    ...
}
```

И дальше используем так:

- `obj.Attributes |= ObjectAttributes.IsCollected` – установка бита
- `obj.Attributes &= ~ObjectAttributes.IsCollected` – обнуление бита
- `obj.Attributes ^= ObjectAttributes.IsCollected` – переключение бита

Где `obj` – ваш объект.

Comment: Где х - это объект?

Comment: Что такое x и n?

Comment: @DenisBredun у вашего объекта должно быть поле с флагами, одним их которых должен быть флаг вашего механизма GC.

Comment: @DenisBredun или же просто используйте `enum`

Comment: А как узнать позицию бита?

Comment: @DenisBredun Эту позицию как бы вы определяете